# SQL Join and filter even further

Tags: sql

I need to add a condition that only selects the rows where a field (my_galleries.format) equals a string value of 'pictures'. I am trying to add it to this working sql statement.

```
SELECT
    gallery_url,
    preview_url
FROM
    my_galleries,
    my_gallery_previews  
WHERE
    my_galleries.gallery_id = my_gallery_previews.gallery_id
```

I tried this, with no luck....

```
SELECT
    gallery_url,
    preview_url 
FROM
    my_galleries,
    my_gallery_previews  
WHERE
    my_galleries.gallery_id = my_gallery_previews.gallery_id 
    AND my_galleries.format='pictures'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the result that you are getting? A side note: use the newer version of [joining tables](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp), not the one you have used.

Comment: Look correct to me.  Perhaps try: select my_galleries.format from my_galleries where my_galleries.format = 'pictures' to see if you have any that match in that table.  If you do, then I suspect your join excludes those rows.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not using the `FROM foo, bar WHERE foo.key = bar.key` approach to performing a `JOIN` as it isn't very flexible and isn't obvious to new readers of your code. Instead you should perform an explicit `JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT
    gallery_url,
    preview_url
FROM
    my_gallery_previews
    INNER JOIN my_galleries ON my_gallery_previews.gallery_id = my_galleries.gallery_id
WHERE
    my_galleries.format = 'pictures'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you try this

```
SELECT gallery_url, preview_url FROM my_galleries 
JOIN my_gallery_previews ON
my_galleries.gallery_id = my_gallery_previews.gallery_id 
WHERE my_galleries.format='pictures'
```

With the join, make sure to prefix your selected columns with their respective tables. I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated I recommend you use the new structure of joining as it is more readable.

```
SELECT mg.gallery_url, 
       mgp.preview_url 
  FROM my_galleries        mg
  JOIN my_gallery_previews mgp ON mg.gallery_id = mgp.gallery_id 
                              AND mg.format = 'pictures'
```

You can place the filter condition in the join using an AND statement. (Just another way to do it)

Your query appears to be correct syntax. I would recommend going through your data set or editing it into your question. It is possible that no picture gallery previews currently share a gallery id with an existing gallery row which is stopping the join from functioning.